# What happens when I press F while selecting two faces?

Tags: modeling

What happens when I press <kbd>F</kbd> while selecting two faces?

If I press <kbd>F</kbd> while selecting two faces, they appears to become merged...
what actually happens?
And if its not the way of joining/merging faces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens for real is a mega-super-wonky N-gon is created using all the vertices that are selected. <kbd>F</kbd> activates the fill tool, it appears to be vertex driven, that means it does recognize when a face is selected, just that there are four more vertices; hitting <kbd>F</kbd> forces blender to try to create a new face with all the vertices you selected as its extremities.

Lets assume that you were using nice, clean mesh, only quads. After selecting two faces, filling them

- destroys the old faces
- form a new 6-8 vertex face (depending on whether or not the faces were adjacent)
- places the origin of the new face at the average of the vertices.

Now, I guess, this is essentially merging the two faces, but its bad form because it causes those dreaded N-gons, and you can see here what the results will be like when the faces aren't flush:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Bridge tool to merge 2 faces. Just press (w) and select 'bridge edge loops'.

Comment: Bridging two edge loops is different than merging faces.  [F] does merge the faces, it just creates bad topology.